# Windows laptop can surf web, but cannot connect to VPN through cell phone hot spot

Tags: networking, vpn

I am using a cell phone as a Wi-Fi hotspot. My Windows 11 laptop can connect to the hotspot and web surfing is good. But the VPN software on the laptop cannot connect to the VPN, Paloalto GlobalProtect, the error message is "The network connection is unreachable or the gateway is not responsive".

My colleague in the same area can connect to the VPN, we both use Windows laptops. The difference is, that her laptop connects to the internet through normal home wifi, not through a cell phone hotspot. Unfortunately, I have to use a cell phone hotspot to connect to the internet.

The cell phone is Android.

What should I check to make my laptop connect to VPN?

Comment: You should ask your VPN provider.

Comment: Does it work when you are using a regular WIFI connection?

Comment: Are your Laptops and VPN clients the same?